Weird Shadows, don't know how to fix it
I found some similar questions but all the solutions didnt work in my case
I flipped normals, tried Autosmooth, also tried to remesh my Object (I would need too small amounts and my blender already froze once)

I thought that it should look "normal" because every face in my mesh is a rectangle, with only 4 vertices on every face (Only the round Caps in the holes have triangles).

Is it my overall creation of the mesh that makes it look so weird?
And how can I fix it


those are interpolation issues that are best explained by shading the default cube smooth. You need your triangles (and so quads) near angle change to be rather small - as small as the size of the gradient you want to have, e.g. for a rather sharp edge, but not super sharp (as in such case you would just mark the edge "sharp") you want very small triangles (quads). So simply speaking, you're missing the buffer of quads around the holes.

Apart from the custom split normals which were the main issue, your geometry is much too unnecessarily complex. I would go with something like this: iphone case simplified. I selected all edges that are not relevant for the shape of the holes and removed them with X > Dissolve Edges (not delete!). I only left a center line, because a hole needs to have at least 2 connecting edges, and theoretically you could then delete either top or bottom half and mirror it. Without mirroring, inside the holes could even be single faces without split in the center.

The split normals (the normals that determine the shading) are messed up, click on the Clear Custom Split Normals Data button:


Ah nice. That worked quite well. Now there are only a few areas where the mesh is rounded and abruptly change to not rounded

Yes you still need to change the topology a bit to avoid bad shading
